# Pandas: Shorten string for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with over 100 columns, a good portion of them are type string but not all of them. I want to find a way to shorten the length each column for those rows that exceed a certain length.

What would be a sensible approach to do this?

I thought about storing which columns I want to transform in a dictionary object where I have the name of the column and the new field length (the stop).

```
columns_dict = {'col1':100, 'col2': 500, 'col3':500 ...}
```

As for the method, I found that `pandas.Series.str.slice` would be what I need. So I'm thinking something along the lines of:

```
def slice_strings(col):
    return col.str.slice(start=0, stop=dict.get(col))
```

The above does not have the condition specified in this case though.

But how would I be able to apply to only those columns and with the appropriate value?

Can I use `pandas.DataFrame.apply`?

```
df = df[df[[list(columns_dict.keys())]].apply(slice_strings, axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a simple loop:

```
for col, stop in columns_dict.items():
    df[col] = df[col].str[:stop]
```

The advantage compared to `apply` is that you will only iterate on the dictionary keys and not all columns if some are excluded.

If you want to handle keys that are not columns:

```
for col, stop in columns_dict.items():
    try:
        df[col] = df[col].str[:stop]
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Comment: Seems like a pretty simple approach. What about case where the values are shorter than the new length, what would happen if I used the df[col].str[:stop]? I wouldn't want to extend their length.

Comment: No this would leave them unchanged